# DLL into Android Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, dll, shared-libraries

I have a huge problem, and I don't get understand it, so please help if you can.

We have a microcontroller library written in C# which has been converted out into a DLL file. It is okay, and nice. I have to write an Android "remote controller" application for the microcontroller, so I have to include the DLL into my Eclipse project, to be able call functions in it. It is not possible (I was not able to do :) ) so I'm trying to convert the DLL using the android NDK, because it is product and .so file.

My first question is, is this the right way?

After I have an so file, I woud like to include into my Eclipse project, but I was not able to do it. :(

Does anyone have any idea what I should do?

Thank you so much,

Comment: what about now?!! I stuck in the same problem of having a .dll libraries in C# which I have to use in android

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to import a dll built in c# directly into any Android application or device.  You probably will need to take all the C# code, convert it to C++, then compile it with the NDK, then create a jni interface, then use that using loadLibrary to actually include the .so in the running java Android app.

Comment: dude, I'd rather kill myself than doing all of that :D , is there isn't an easier way to achieve that?

Comment: DLLs still cannot and will never be able to be used directly. A new option called Xamarian at least might allow you to recompile the C# on Android. But if the C# is using low level device drivers etc for the microcontroller that is never going to work on Android. It needs to be rewritten. If it just uses Bluetooth or something then the Xamarian route might help you.

Comment: The problem is that I'm a native developer and I didn't use Xamarian once before, and what bothers me is that the dll files can be included easily in Java but when coming to android it wouldn't